# Is there a python picam gui out there?

Tags: raspicam, gui, tkinter

Before starting to code a new GUI in tkinter (or something similar) for picam, I was wondering if there is something already available. What I am looking for is a simple GUI to set the picam parameters (ie. frame rate, shutter, etc) and a rec button.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched before you asked?

Comment: Yes, I did. That is why I asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are various GUI tools that can control the Pi Camera without having to mess with the code yourself. One such example is [PiCameraApp](https://github.com/Billwilliams1952/PiCameraApp) by Billwilliams1952 (available on GitHub). It is described as:

> A graphical user interface (GUI) for the Picamera library written in Python using Tkinter / ttk.

An image of the user interface is available [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3778024/20574032/44029314-b178-11e6-90f5-243d38602be0.png), and it appears to offer options to take photos, record and adjust various other parameters. Sounds like this is pretty similar to what you were intending – even using the same language and GUI toolkit.

Alternatively, there is [Pi Vision](http://heywhatsthebigidea.net/projects/pi-vision-a-raspberry-pi-camera-controller/) (also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/local-vision/Pi-Vision)) that appears pretty well developed. This one does allow both photos and (timed) videos to be taken on the Pi.

There are other, perhaps less advanced options available too, such as ['Graphical interface for raspistill'](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=374577) on the Raspberry Pi forums. That particular program doesn't appear to support video recording, but it is relatively simple to use by the looks of it.